# <proj>.exe.config - is there a correspondent thing in .net6 for WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I used to program WinForm .net Framework Applications. There I used the .exe.config (via "Settings" - Scope "Application" in VS).
With that, I could change the entries of the .config file after being deployed, and I was able to access these changed entries easyly via Properties.Settings.Default..

Is there an easy way to do similar things in .net6 WinForms? I couldn't find "the whole story" anywhere (how to define such settings, how to make them editable after having compiled the program and how to access the Settings in cSharp.

Comment: Yes, the [configuration middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration). It's *far* easier to customize than the old `app.config` and can load settings from multiple sources, including JSON files, the command line, environment variables, databases, cloud providers like Azure. The default setup used by web and worker templates (ie anywhere a Host is used) is to use JSON files, environment variables and the command line

Comment: It still exists and works the same way when you use System.Configuration.  Use Project > Add New Item > "Application Configuration File".  Then Project > Properties > Settings, "Open or create" and the IDE will start adding entries to the app.config file.